# Blender for loop relocation

Tags: python, for-loop, blender

I'm trying to make a loop, which is moving object beyond the previous

like that

```
 cube50 - move to 50y

 cube100 - move to 50y + 100

 cube400 - move to 150y + 400
```

but I have trouble with loop, my idea was **location = locationY + dimensionY**

```
import bpy

for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob

Y = ob.dimensions[1]
for Y in ob:
    ob.location[1] = ob.dimensions[1] + Y
```

but meh... hope some one can help ^_^

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking about?

Comment: get some help with a loop

Comment: I don't know enough about blender to completely follow the code. What is the inner loop supposed to be looping over? Vertices or something? If the outer loop is over several objects, and each object has just the one location to update, it doesn't seem like you should need the inner loop at all.

Comment: the first loop goes through selected objects, the second one make relocation, but my main problem that every next loop count from 0 instead of last object location

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the second one make relocation". How does relocating an object relate to looping on it? `ob` is an blender object, right? What is `Y` going to be inside `for Y in ob`? I'm pretty sure that's nonsense. Anyway, you should tell us what is happening with your code. Are you getting exceptions? Is it crashing blender? Is it just doing nothing? Have you made any debugging efforts yet?

Comment: you should know about how blender work, object must be active to provide some manipulation

`for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = ob`

after that I need some help, I show what I try, but 

 `loc1 = ob.dimensions[1]
 ob.location[1] = loc1

loc2 = loc1 + ob.location[1]*2
ob.location[1] = loc2`

that work, just like on the screenshot, read it OP post again

Comment: The answer answer answer answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63374/iterate-through-all-selected-objects-but-do-a-different-operation-to-each-one